# How to check if any one of several pointers is null?

Tags: c, logic

I have several pointer/integer variables and I want to check if any of them is 0. Right now I compare each to 0 in a large if statement that would short circuit once it hits one that is 0. I was wondering if there is any more clever or faster way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I have a box of coins and I want to check if any of them are heads up. Right now I check each one to see if it is heads up or tails up until I find one that is heads up, and then I stop because I know the answer. *Is there a more clever way?*

Comment: Think about this - in the case of a boolean situation like that I could AND all the variables together and do one comparison to 0. That could potentially be more efficient than doing a bunch of comparisons to 0. So I was wondering if there was something like that for integers.

Comment: I see. So suppose there are ten million bools and you want to know if any of them are false. Suppose one million of them are false. Your idea is you will AND together all ten million of them, instead of just checking them one at a time, which will find the answer on average after ten tries. Your suggestion seems like the less efficient suggestion; AND is not free.

Comment: I said "several" in the question which clearly is not 10 million.

Comment: All right, suppose there are ten, and on average one in ten is false. ANDing together ten of them takes ten ANDs. Checking each one to see if it is false takes between one and ten checks, averaging around five. I'm still not seeing how using AND is more clever; it seems to be less clever.

Comment: I'm no expert but I would think an AND instruction would take less cycles than a comparison and jump. I could be wrong about that. And your assumption about 1 in 10 values being 0 is very situation dependent. For my situation, which I didn't fully elaborate on in the question, it would be rare to have a 0. But in any case you have shown that the AND approach probably doesn't scale well even if it works for small amounts of values.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter. Even if you'd stack all pointers up and loop over this array or if you or-ed all values.. you'd still have to do that one after another. And if you have something like this `if( a != 0 && b != 0 && .. && z != null)` the compiler will convert that to as many instructions as it will need in all other cases.

The only thing you might could save using an array which you e.g. you loop over is maybe memory at some point but I don't think this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Think about it: to really be sure that not a single one of your values is zero, you absolutely have to look at each an every one of them. As you correctly noted, it is possible to short-circuit, one a zero-value has been found. I would recommend something similar to this:

```
int has_null = -1;
for(int i=0; i < null_list_len && has_null &= null_list[i]; ++i)
  ;

if(has_null)
  //do stuff
```

You can improve the run time, if you have more assumptions about the values you are testing. If, for example you knew, that the `null_list` array is sorted, you only have to check wether the very first entry is zero, as a non-zero entry would imply that all other values are also greater than zero.

Comment: I don't think AND-ing the values will give the desired outcome - it doesn't necessarily check whether a value in the list is 0, but whether there is a 0 at in at least one of the values for each bit position.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could code whatever it is that sets the vars to zero to ensure that a common boolean is set to 'true'.

Checking would then be a matter of testing one boolean, no matter how many vars there are.  If the bool is true, then you can do a sequential check, much as you are doing now.

That may, or may not, be possible, faster, or more efficient, overall, (or not).